# Prove $|\log(1-x)+x|\leqslant cx^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> **Problem**: Prove $|\log(1-x)+x|\leqslant cx^2$*(c is a constant)*
>   holds for $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$.

**My proof**:
$\log(x-1)=-x-O(x^2)$ then
$\log(x-1)+x=-x-O(x^2)+x\implies \log(x-1)+x=O(x^2)\implies|\log(x-1)+x|=O(x^2)\implies |\log(x-1)+x|\leqslant cx^2$

However the author points out that the latter identity only holds for $|x|⩽\frac{1}{2}$. This later point did not show in my derivation.

**Question**:

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a continuous function, $f(x)=\frac{\log(1-x)+x}{x^2}$ for $|x|\leq 1/2$ has MAX and MIN value!

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo $|x|\leqslant1/2$.

Comment: @user108128 Yes it was indeed a typo. Thanks for pointing that out. I have already corrected it.

Comment: In your attempt you have written $\log (x-1)$. Is that a typo ? It's hard to critique a proof with typos in it.

Comment: @Riemann . Best one-liner I've seen this week.

Comment: It is obvious since $\log(1-x)$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood ($|x|<1$) of the origin and the first term of the Maclaurin series of $\log(1-x)$ is $-x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kavi Rama Murthy has explained why the OP's work is invalid.  I am presenting an explicit way to extract such a constant $c$.

By Taylor's Theorem, we have $$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{1}{2}\,x^2-\frac{1}{3\,\big(1-\xi(x)\big)^3}\,x^3\text{ for all }x<1\,,$$
where $\xi(x)$ is a number between $0$ and $x$.
That is,
$$-\ln(1-x)-x\leq \frac{1}{2}\,x^2+\frac{1}{3\,\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3}\,\left(x^2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{11}{6}\,x^2\text{ if }0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$-\ln(1-x)-x\leq \frac{1}{2}x^2\text{ if }x<0\,.$$
That is,
$$\big|\ln(1-x)+x\big|\leq \frac{11}{6}\,x^2\text{ for all }x\in\left[-\frac12,+\frac12\right]\,.$$

---

In fact, let $f:\mathbb{R}_{<1}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{-x-\ln(1-x)}{x^2}\,,&\text{if }x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\,,\\
\frac{1}{2}\,,&\text{if }x=0\,.
\end{array}\right.$$  Then, $f$ is an increasing positive function.  Therefore, the best constant $c$ in this problem is $$f\left(\dfrac12\right)=4\,\ln(2)-2\approx 0.77259\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for you proof! I have been reading your proof but I have got some questions. First you explain correctly by the rest of the expansion that $x<1$ but on the following step you take on the interval $(0,1)$, $\xi(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Why $\frac{1}{2}$? Was it random? Then you compute $c=\frac{11}{6}$, however I do not understand what follows next. Why $f(\frac{1}{2})=c$? What is this later part about? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I only dealt with the assumption that $|x|<\frac12$.  There is no such constant $c$ if you only assume $|x|<1$, as Kavi Rama Murphy said.

Comment: For $0\leq x<\frac12$, we have $0\leq \xi(x)\leq x$, so that $\xi(x)<\frac12$.  Thus, $$\frac{1}{\big(1-\xi(x)\big)^3}\leq \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac12\right)^3}\,.$$

Comment: For the last part, I noted (without proof, and will not be giving a proof) that the function $f$ is an increasing positive function.  Thus, we have $$\big|x+\ln(1-x)\big|=x^2\,f(x)\leq x^2\cdot f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ for all $|x|\leq \frac12$.  Since the equality holds for $x=\frac12$, $c:=f\left(\frac12\right)$ is the optimal (smallest) value of $c$.

Answer (score 2):

For $|x|<1,$ $\ln (1-x) =-(x+x^2/2+x^3/3 + \cdots)$ Thus

$$\ln (1-x) + x = -(x^2/2+x^3/3 + \cdots)$$

This gives

$$|\ln (1-x) + x| \le |x^2/2+x^3/3 + \cdots)| \le x^2(1/2 + |x|/3 + |x|^2/4 +\cdots)$$ $$ \le x^2(1+|x|+|x|^2+ \cdots) = x^2/(1-|x|).$$

If we now use $|x|\le 1/2,$ we see the last expression is $\le x^2(1-1/2) = 2x^2.$ So we may take $c=2.$

Answer (score 1):

$\log (1-x)$ is defined only for $x<1$.  As $x$ increases to $1$, $\log (1-x)+x \to =-\infty$ so the inequality cannot be true for $x$ near $1$. The question you have to think about is: what exactly is the meaning of $O(x^{2})$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your proof in this way:
$$\log(1-x)+x=-x+O(x^2)+x=O(x^2)$$
so there is a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|\log(1-x)+x|\leqslant cx^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I got to your later expression. What should I do then?

Comment: You've done. Good job.

Comment: Your inequality is right locally, but  Pedro Gomes wants to a global inequality on the closed interval $[-1/2,1/2]$ .

Comment: Of course. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\log(1-x)+x}{x^2},x\in[-1/2,0)\cup(0,1/2]$ and $f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1-x)+x}{x^2}$.
So $f(x)$ is a continuous function defined on the compact set [-1/2,1/2].
Therefore, the function $f(x)$ has Maximum and minimum denoted by $M$ and $m$ respectively.
So $|f(x)|\leq C$, where $C=max\{|M|,|m|\}$ for $x\in[-1/2,1/2]$.
And then $$\left|\log(1-x)+x\right|\leq Cx^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do you define your first interval?

Comment: Define $f(x)=\frac{\log(1-x)+x}{x^2},x\in[-1/2,0)\cup(0,1/2]$.

Comment: I want to know why you defined the function that way. Could I have chosen any random interval?

Comment: Fist , your inequality is right when $x=0$, and in this case you can choose $c$ to be any positive number. And then you need prove you inequality is right on $[-1/2,0)\cup(0,1/2]$, and in this case, you can Divide $x^2$ in both side because in the case $x\neq 0$.